# How to suppress the carriage return in python 2?

Tags: python, io

```
        myfile = open("wrsu"+str(i)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(TimesToExec)+".txt",'w')
        sys.stdout = myfile
        p1 = subprocess.Popen([pathname,"r", "s","u",str(i),str(j),str(runTime)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = p1.communicate()[0]
        print output,
```

When I use this to redirect the output of a exe to my own file, it always

a carriage return after each line, How to suppress it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I removed the carriage return:

```
 p = Popen([vmrun_cmd, list_arg], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
 for line in p.splitlines():
 if line.strip():
     print line
```

Comment: Hi, the `line.strip()` is not necessary to remove '\n's, as split lines already does the job:  `'one\ntwo\nthree'.splitlines()  --> ['one', 'two', 'three']`

Comment: True. But also consider that strip() also removes leading or trailing white space characters like space. That said, you may, or may not, want that depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Popenstrip(self):
  p = Popen([vmrun_cmd, list_arg], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
  return (line for line in p.splitlines() if line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print line.rstrip('\r\n')
```

will do fine.